# Compute variance-covariance matrix of adjusted means in R `lme4`

Tags: r, mixed-model, lme4-nlme

I am trying to fit some mixed models for unbalanced data as follows.

```
library(easyanova)
data(data13)
```

#### 1) `genotypes` as random

```
frmla <- "yield ~ 1 + (1|blocks) + (1|genotypes)"

model1 <- lmer(formula(frmla), data = data13)

# adjusted means - BLUPs for genotypes
newdata13 <- expand.grid(genotypes = levels(data13$genotypes), blocks = levels(data13$blocks))
newdata13$pred <- predict(model1, newdata=newdata13)
tapply(newdata13$pred, newdata13$genotypes, mean)
```

#### 1) `genotypes` as fixed

```
frmla <- "yield ~ 1 + (1|blocks) + genotypes"

model2 <- lmer(formula(frmla), data = data13)

# adjusted means - BLUEs for genotypes
newdata13 <- expand.grid(genotypes = levels(data13$genotypes), blocks = levels(data13$blocks))
newdata13$pred <- predict(model2, newdata=newdata13)
tapply(newdata13$pred, newdata13$genotypes, mean)
```

For further calculations I need to compute **mean variance of difference of adjusted means** (BLUPs or BLUEs). A method is given (https://static-content.springer.com/esm/art%3A10.1186%2F1471-2164-14-860/MediaObjects/12864_2013_5591_MOESM1_ESM.doc)
to compute it from **variance-covariance matrix of adjusted means**.

How to get the variance-covariance matrix of adjusted means for `model1` and `model2` ?

When `genotypes` are fixed in `model2` does `vcov(model2)` give the variance-covariance matrix of adjusted means ?